# Assign specific files to specific directories

Tags: html, web

I am wondering how I can make my website go to a certain file when accessing a certain directory.

for example `www.google.com/vote`. I wish for that to take me to `www.google.com/vote.html`.

Comment: I found a 'hack' for it. However I don't think this is a good solution for it but it is a solution. 
I made a directory called /vote/ then I renamed me vote.html file to index.html.
now it works but i must fix all the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use redirects in your .htaccess file. It would be something like:

```
Redirect 301 http://www.google.com/vote http://www.google.com/vote.html
```

You can find more info on htaccess here: http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/